# How to destroy objects in .Net

Tags: .net, object, heap-memory

I know this is a strange question, but really I'm very excited to know the answer.
How do you destroy Objects in .Net, and give memory back to the heap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

is suppose to force the garbage collection to run but I've heard that its more of a polite asking function that may not actually have it run.

**Long Answer**

I believe C# uses garbage collection, so at best you can ask it to clean up but it really does it on its own time. An object is considered destroyed when there are no references to it.

For example:

```
Object myobject = new Object();
Object sameobject = myobject;
myobject = null;
//Garbage collection will not clean it up because sameobject is still pointing to the memory location
sameobject = null;
//Garbage collection can now clean it up
```

Here's a great article on the [garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) .NET uses

Answer (score 5):

You can't, and you shouldn't try.

When there are no more used references to an object, it's eligable for garbage collection, and will be removed if there is opportunity or if the memory is needed.

The garbage collector takes care of removing objects, and you should let it do it's job without trying to interfer. There is no value in itself to try to keep memory usage down, a computer doesn't run faster from having a lot of unused memory. Trying to make the garbage collector free up memory earlier will only make your application slower.

You can ask the garbage collector to run a collection, but there is no guarantee that it will actually do one at that time, and even if it does one, there is no guarantee that any given object will be collected. You have no way of controlling when a specific object will be collected.

Answer (score 4):

It's done automatically because it's a managed language.  The Common Language Runtime has a garbage collector, which keeps track of objects on the heap that can't be referenced anymore and makes the space they consume available at some point (which is indeterminate; therefore .NET has no "destructors" in the sense of C++).

Comment: :) thanks for your fast reply 
but what if i define an object of such a border [ WPF example ] then i don't want to use it .. i want to destroy it ??

Comment: @Ahmed Adel you mean you've defined it in code? Have you assigned it to anything other than an instance variable? If you set all references to it to `null`, it ought to be GCed...