# How to destroy temp object correctly c#

Tags: c#

I need a help with creation and destruction of objects or life cycle of objects.
Problem is that after Disposing form temp objects are not erased and relations with object are still exists.
What I am doing wrong? Do I need to override dispose method or destructor somehow?
How to destroy temp object correctly? Thanks.

Product Form:

```
private Product T = null;

public ProductForm(Customer cust)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    T = new Product();
    T.Customer = cust;
}

Public CopyProducts(List<Product> copy_from)
{
    Foreach(Product Temp1 in copy_from) 
    {
        Product Temp2 = new Product();
        Temp2.Customer = T.Customer;
        Temp2.Count = Temp1.Count;
        Temp2.Delivery =  Temp1. Delivery;
        …
        cDB.Product.InsertOnSubmit(Temp2);
        cDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
}

private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    T.Count = …
    …
    cDB.Product.InsertOnSubmit(T);
    cDB.SubmitChanges();
}

private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();           
}
```

Test code in main form:

```
MessageBox.Show(current_customer.Product.Count().ToString()); // ->>> 10
ProductForm prodform = new ProductForm(current_customer);
prodform.ShowDialog();
prodform.Dispose();
// ->>> after cancel button clicked should be 10 but it shouws 11
MessageBox.Show(current_customer.Product.Count().ToString()); // ->>> 11 instead of 10
```

and

```
MessageBox.Show(current_customer.Product.Count().ToString()); // ->>> 10
ProductForm prodform = new ProductForm(current_customer);
prodform.CopyProducts(list_of_products);
prodform.Dispose();
MessageBox.Show(current_customer.Product.Count().ToString()); // ->>> 11 instead of 10
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Linq?

Comment: You don't need to dispose it, let the garbage collector do it's job.

Comment: But it doesn't. Example code shows this. What's why I am asking.

Comment: Dispose will be called automatically if the form is shown using the Show method. If another method such as ShowDialog is used, or the form is never shown at all, you must call Dispose yourself within your application. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aw58wzka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Go look at this SO question about garbage collection
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737594/how-to-destroy-objects-in-net

Answer (score 0):

When disposing your form this does not affect your current_customer because it has nothing to do with it. When you dispose your form only one reference to your instance current_customer is released, but as long as references exist (within your main app e.g.) the actual instance exists further. Therefor it still ha its value.

EDIT: Maybe you can show some more code where you increment that count.

Comment: If I add T.Customer = null; in CancelButton_Click - everything works fine after cancell button was clicked. But prodform.CopyProducts(list_of_products) still doesn't work fine.

Comment: Where do you declare current_customer?

Comment: In the main form. I get it from datacontext. Customer = cDB.Customer.First(x=> x.Custemer_id == id_selected);

Comment: Can you show the complete code? Espacially the method where the two parts at the end are called.